# open a tmp/log file in append mode in zf2

Tags: php, authentication, logging, zend-framework2, ldap

I am using a ZF2 Zend logger to append a log data as like:

```
$logger = new Logger;
$writer = new LogWriter($log_path);
```

for appending log message while implementing LDAP authentication.

But I am getting error message as below:

```
File:
E:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Log\Writer\Stream.php:82


Message:
  "/tmp/ldap.log" cannot be opened with mode "a"
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
   $logdir = "tmp/";
   // check if the log dir exists
   if (!file_exists($logdir)) {
       mkdir($logdir, 0777, true);
   }

   $stream = fopen($logdir . "ldap.log", 'a', false);
   $writer = new Stream($stream);
   $logger = new Logger();
   $logger->addWriter($writer);
   // add your message
   $message = "log appended to file at ".time();
   $logger->info($message)
```

Also make sure that the file has the proper write permission

```
   chmod 777 /tmp/ldap.log
```